# UI Alert Search Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an iOS scanner app and I'm stuck on a part where I want when the user clicks the search UI Alert search function to search the Firebase Database if the object exists in the Firebase.

Heres my code below along my database is in a JSON format:

```
// Get the metadata object.
    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if self.allowedTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {

        // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds


        //This code vibrates the device to notify the user that there is a barcode!
        //AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))


        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds;

        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Found a Barcode!", message: metadataObj.stringValue, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Search", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { action in

                self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()




                //(result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                //print("OK")
            }




          alert.addAction(okAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        //AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))



    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with your JSON data structure. Also which node you want to check... Is it username related?

Comment: Okay so I'm able to print my JSON file from firebase in the console but I'm unable to load it to my table.